# How to correctly override the SaveChanges function in EF 4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I need to automatically insert the current date when I create a new order in my EF 4.1 MVC3 web application. I also need to automatically add the currently logged in user - I'm using forms authentication.
After searching the web, I found that I need to override the SaveChanges() function and an article on StackOverflow showed how to do this: [Entity Framework 4.1 Automatic date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465438/entity-framework-4-1-automatic-date). However, I couldn't get the code to work.
Where does this code go?
How do I find out what  is?

Sorry if the question is trivial - I'm new to EF.
B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override in your context class,

```
public partial class YourDbContext: DbContext
    {
      public  YourDbContext()
        {               
        }
      public override int SaveChanges()
      {
       // do your additional stuff here.. (Ex:- save current user)
           return base.SaveChanges();
      }   
}
```

And the other option is you can set default values in the constructor of your entity,

```
   Public class YourEntity{

      public YourEntity(){
          CreatedDate=DateTime.Now;
      }

      Public DateTime CreatedDate{get;set;}
   }
```

Comment: Setting the default values in the constructor worked perfectly. Thanks very much. B.