# ASP.NET MVC3 Need to change default fields for web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a simple asp.net mvc3 project with entity framework 4.1.
I asked a previous question and the answer worked well - [How to correctly override the SaveChanges function in EF 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300330/how-to-correctly-override-the-savechanges-function-in-ef-4-1)
The values for date and loggedby were set in the class constructor. This was fine for the Create action but when I used the Edit action, I saw that the date and LoggedBy fields were changed, which I don't want. I also see that Delete doesn't work - I'm guessing that this is because of the constructor.
How do I solve this so that my Date and LoggedBy values are set for Create but not changed during Edit?
B.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

public partial class tblDefectDetail
{
    public tblDefectDetail()
    {
        DateLogged = DateTime.Now;
        LoggedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Project { get; set; }
    public string LoggedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateLogged { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; }
```

My Action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.BugLocation = new SelectList(db.tblBugLocations, "ID", "BugLocation");
            ViewBag.BugType = new SelectList(db.tblBugTypes, "ID", "BugType");
            ViewBag.BusinessUnit = new SelectList(db.tblBusinessUnits, "ID", "BU_Name");
            ViewBag.BugFoundMethod = new SelectList(db.tblDefectDiscoveryMethods, "ID", "DiscoveryMethod");
            ViewBag.Project = new SelectList(db.tblProjects, "ID", "ProjectName");
            ViewBag.Language = new SelectList(db.tblLanguages, "ID", "Language");
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting your values in the constructor, set them in your Action method.  So before you pass your model to the view, set the values you want in the Create action method.

```
public ActionResult Create() {
    var model = new tblDefectDetail() { LoggedBy = User.Identity.Name, DateLogged = DateTime.Now }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for not getting back to you sooner. This seems like the way to go. However, my current Action method looks like the following. When I added your code, I got an exception. How should I modify it?

Comment: Code for Action Create() added to original post.

Comment: @bearaman - my code was an example, you need to figure out how best to make it work for you.  You really should be using a view model rather than passing everything in ViewBag.

Comment: Thanks Mystere Man. This was the code that was auto generated by EF. I'll do some research and post the answer here. Thanks for your time. B.